# How to save and restore multiple values inside a form field (using front-end logic only)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, save, restore

I am looking for a way to save table values from multiple `<input>` form fields, and be able to restore them.  Why -- I need to have a way of switching between English and Metric systems, without losing precision during conversion.

So what I have below is some code that assumes that values are entered in English unit system.  If user then switches to Metric, `the values are converted` for the user.  Switching back to English right now does nothing, because while I can do a reverse conversion, doing so will lose precision eventually.  I don't know how to approach the problem of saving and restoring multiple values, and what I want the form to do is is to `restore originally entered values` when user switches to English.  I assume I will first need to have a way to save values upon original entry.

When trying code below, first change the selection from English to Metric.  You will see all values change to some converted value.  Going back to English does nothing.  Save and Restore buttons do nothing right now as well.  Also, there is no differentiation between individual values as I don't know how to encode them.  I don't want to assign unique IDs to each, unless I have to.  (so i.e. right now entering your own values will get ignored, and only the first row first cell will have impact the remaining cells, when you do conversions, since I am using a class selector for the cells, and not selecting them each individually)

What I need help with:

- How do I address individual values?  Must I generate and assign a unique id to them?
- How to I save these values -- I can do so implicitly upon entry, or explicitly via "Save" button
- How do I restore values -- they can be explicitly restored via "Restore" button, or implicitly via select box, when changing back to original system of units

Edit to mention PHP:

"Add Row" does nothing but programmatically here, but it means that more rows could be added.  Right now it is done via PHP -- a form post is issued to the server back-end, and page refreshes with an extra row.  So there is a way to use PHP to generate some of the HTML if need be.  As in, the solution does not have to be front-end only, but I figure the more loosely coupled PHP and front ends are, the better.  So if there is a front-end only (JS/jQuery) solution I will prefer it first, rather than a hybrid JS/PHP approach, but I will accept both.

```js
$("#unit_system").change(function() {
   
       if ($('#unit_system').val() == "Metric")
       {
           $(".input_gpm").val(convert($(".input_gpm").val(),'gpm','m3h'));
       }
   });

   

   function convert(val, from, to)
   {
       var conv = [];
       conv["m3h"] = 1 / 3600;
       conv["gpm"] = 6.3090196485533854530026767050539e-5;
       return val * conv[from] / conv[to];
   };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form">
 <select id="unit_system">
  <option value="English">English</option>
  <option value="Metric">Metric</option>
 </select>

 <button id="save_values" type="button">Save Values</button>
 <button id="restore_values" type="button">Restore Values</button>
 <table id="values">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1</td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2</td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><button>Add Row...</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store and retrieve arbitrary data for each input on your page. I've created a runnable example below. Take a look at the handlers I created for your "Save" and "Restore" buttons at the bottom of the code.

**Edit**: I just saw the requirement for the "Add Row" button and I added an event handler for this as well.

```js
$("#unit_system").change(function() {
  if ($('#unit_system').val() == "Metric") {
    $(".input_gpm").val(convert($(".input_gpm").val(),'gpm','m3h'));
  }
});

function convert(val, from, to) {
  var conv = [];
  conv["m3h"] = 1 / 3600;
  conv["gpm"] = 6.3090196485533854530026767050539e-5;
  return val * conv[from] / conv[to];
};

$("#save_values").on("click", function() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    $(this).data("restore", $(this).val());
  });
});

$("#restore_values").on("click", function() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data("restore"));
  });
});

$("#addNew").on("click", function() {
  var lastDataRow = $("#values tr:nth-last-of-type(2)");
  var newDataRow = lastDataRow.clone();
  newDataRow.find("td:first").html("Row " + $("#values tr").length);
  lastDataRow.after(newDataRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form">
 <select id="unit_system">
  <option value="English">English</option>
  <option value="Metric">Metric</option>
 </select>

 <button id="save_values" type="button">Save Values</button>
 <button id="restore_values" type="button">Restore Values</button>
 <table id="values">
  <tr>
   <td>Row 1</td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 2</td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Row 3</td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
   <td><input class="input_gpm" type="text" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><button id="addNew">Add Row...</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution for all questions, but just an approach how you can take care about storing and restoring the current metric or english values in corresponding data-attributes. Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxgrnL7f/):

```
$("#unit_system").change(function () {

  if ($('#unit_system').val() == "Metric") {
    $(".input_gpm").each(function () {
        $(this).data("english", 
               $(this).val()).val(convert($(this).val(), 'gpm', 'm3h'))
    });
  } else
  {
    $(".input_gpm").each(function () {
        $(this).data("metric", 
        $(this).val()).val($(this).data("english"));
    });
  }
});
```